# How do I take this code that sends emails automatically based on the value and make it send an email based on the date?

Tags: vba, excel, email

Here's the code: 
currently I have a spreadsheet that will send emails if a value in the table goes above 200, I want to make it so that it will send a reminder email saying "You have a program due NEXT Wednesday" 9 days before, and one saying "You have a program due THIS Wednesday" 2 days before. Any help is appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim FormulaRange As Range
    Dim NotSentMsg As String
    Dim MyMsg As String
    Dim SentMsg As String
    Dim MyLimit As Double

    NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
    SentMsg = "Sent"

    'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
    MyLimit = 200

    'Set the range with Formulas that you want to check
    Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("B3:B7")

    On Error GoTo EndMacro:
    For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
        With FormulaCell
            If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
                MyMsg = "Not numeric"
            Else
                If .Value > MyLimit Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_with_outlook2
                    End If
                Else
                    MyMsg = NotSentMsg
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
    Exit Sub

EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
         & vbLf & Err.Number _
         & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: post a few rows of your table, please